# TThread and COM - "CoInitialize has not been called", although CoInitialize is called in the constructor

Tags: multithreading, delphi, com, ole, tthread

I'm trying to use COM interface within a thread. From what I have read I have to call `CoInitialize/CoUninitialize` in each thread.

While this is working fine:

```
procedure TThreadedJob.Execute;
begin
   CoInitialize(nil);

   // some COM stuff

   CoUninitialize;
end;
```

when I move the calls to constructor and destructor:

```
TThreadedJob = class(TThread)
...
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
...

constructor TThreadedJob.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  CoInitialize(nil);
end;

destructor TThreadedJob.Destroy;
begin
  CoUninitialize;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TThreadedJob.Execute;
begin

   // some COM stuff

end;
```

I get **EOleException: CoInitialize has not been called** exception and I have no clue why.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`CoInitialize` initializes COM for the executing thread. The constuctor of a `TThread` instance executes in the thread that creates the `TThread` instance. The code in the `Execute` method executes in the new thread.

This means that if you need your `TThreadedJob` thread to have COM initialized, then you must call `CoInitialize` in the `Execute` method. Or a method called from `Execute`. The following is correct:

```
procedure TThreadedJob.Execute;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try    
    // some COM stuff
  finally  
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for lightning fast answer.